# DigiSHOP duplicate order emails

Tags: php, email, e-commerce

A client's site is running DigiSHOP. We recently started getting duplicate order emails. The orders themselves are not duplicated, but we are receiving some order emails 2-5 times. This only seems to be happening with Paypal orders, but I have no idea why. SumEffect (DigiSHOP creators) and the hosting company have been no help. My next step is to talk with Paypal, since it seems to only be happening with their orders, but not all the time.

Comment: Noticed u didnt actually ask a question there haha. Has the client mage changes to their (for lack of a better word) install of DigiSHOP? if so, they mightve made a mistake in the mailer thats causing it to sometimes send duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that one of the email addresses to which the notifications are sent is NOT a group or list type address that includes the other people who are receiving the email. This has happened to me many times resulting in dupes.

Answer (score 0):

There's no group mailer in the list. I've since added myself to the list of recipients. There's no pattern to the duplicate emails, other than it only happens with Paypal orders. I would assume that if there were a group on the list, all emails would be duplicated, but it's only some of them. Thanks for the help though.